# keycloak-angular: isLoggedIn() always false after page reload

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

I am trying to secure a Spring Boot Application with Angular as frontend.
Therefore I am using keycloak-angular and keycloak-js.

In every example you can find, it is always assumed that all routes should be secured.
I now have some routes that are openly accessible:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    resolve: {
      data: LayoutResolver
    }
},
{
    path: 'add-news',
    component: AddNewsComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard]
},
```

My APP_INITIALIZER looks like this:

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: environment.keycloakUrl,
        realm: environment.keycloakRealm,
        clientId: environment.keycloakClientId,

      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
      }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine.
However, when I am on the dashboard and reload the page, I seem to lose my authentication. keycloakService.isLoggedIn always returns "false". What am I doing wrong? I expect to still be logged in in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the keycloak server and everything worked. I must have broken it while renaming the realm and client.

Answer (score 0):

For us the solution was to add:

```
onload: 'check-sso'
```

to the `initOptions` in the `keycloak.init` method.

Thanks to a colleague